$1$-varifold $V$ associated varifold of the reduced boundary of some Caccioppoli set
Let $v_1$, $v_2$, $\cdots$, $v_l\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be unit vectors, $\mathbb{R}_v^+:=\{\lambda v:\lambda>0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be the ray in $v$'s direction; $n_1$, $n_2$, $\cdots$, $n_l>0$ be integers. I've proved that the $1$-varifold given by
$$V=\sum_{j=i}^l n_j|\mathbb{R}_{v_j}^+|$$
is stationary if and only if the following balancing condition is satisfied in $\mathbb{R}^n$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^ln_jv_j=\mathbf{0}.$$
Now my question is when $n=2$, what are the conditions on $v_j$, $n_j$ so that the $1$-varifold $V$ above is the associated varifold of the reduced boundary of some Caccioppoli set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Any comments and answers are appreciated!

Great Question! I have an analogous question.

Actually I still don't know how to prove the balancing condition...
